# Is it possible to have ressources in other project (Spring Boot)?

Tags: mysql, jpa, geolocation, spring-data-jpa

I want to work with MySQL 10 and Point for Geolocations.
My property for the dialect is :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

On my Entity I use at the Moment:

```
@Column(name="location", columnDefinition = "POINT") 
private org.springframework.data.geo.Point location;
```

The error message is:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

I try to save it with a JpaRepository => save()

Is it possible with JPA?

Answer (score 0):

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.h2geodb.GeoDBDialect
try with both versions of dialect not sure which one will suit your needs

Comment: When i use the first i get the message :
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

And the second is for a h2 Database and won't fit :(

Comment: Post your Pom or grade config it should be dependency issue